# using strong parameters for a server-side autocomplete resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

playing around with [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/399-autocomplete-search-terms?autoplay=true), except I'm using Rails 5 where attr_accessible is deprecated. `VenueSuggestion` is a resource for suggesting venues in the db as user types something in the related field of a form. the problem I'm having right now is that as I start typing things that match db contents, there are no search results.

the model:

```
class VenueSuggestion < ApplicationRecord

  # should anything go in place of attr_accessible?

  def self.terms_for(prefix)
    suggestions = where("term like ?", "#{prefix}_%")
    suggestions.order("popularity desc").limit(10).pluck(:term)
  end

  def self.index_venues
    Venue.find_each do |venue|
      index_term(venue.name)
      index_term(venue.address)
      venue.name.split.each { |t| index_term(t) }
    end
  end

  def self.index_term(term)
    where(term: term.downcase).first_or_initialize.tap do |suggestion|
      suggestion.increment! :popularity
    end
  end
end
```

the controller:

```
class VenueSuggestionsController < ApplicationController
  #is this right?
  def create
    VenueSuggestion.create(params[:venue_suggestion])
  end

  def index
    render json: VenueSuggestion.terms_for(params[:term])
  end

  # is this right?
  private
        def venue_suggestion_params
            params.require(:venue_suggestion).permit(:term, :popularity)
        end
end
```

the rake task:

```
namespace :venue_suggestions do
  desc "Generate venue suggestions for event form"
  task :index => :environment do
    VenueSuggestion.index_venues
  end
end
```

what the log shows:

```
Started GET "/venue_suggestions?term=sp" for ::1 at 2016-05-25 21:27:31 -0400
Processing by VenueSuggestionsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"term"=>"sp"}
   (1.4ms)  SELECT  "venue_suggestions"."term" FROM "venue_suggestions" WHERE (term like 'sp_%') ORDER BY popularity desc LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 10]]
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (0.06ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Comment: Your strong parameters look good. http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: Keep in mind that you will need to specify `term` inside `venue_suggestions` with something like `{venue_suggestion: { term: "something" } }`

Comment: @HarlemSquirrel could you elaborate more, where would a line like that go?

Comment: That would be how you are passing params to the controller.

Comment: I think you want `Parameters: {"venue_suggestion" => {"term"=>"sp"}}

Answer (score 0):

The strong params features provides an interface for protecting attributes from end-user assignment. This makes Action Controller parameters forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignment until they have been whitelisted.

```
class PeopleController < ActionController::Base
  # Using "Person.create(params[:person])" would raise an
  # ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes exception because it'd
  # be using mass assignment without an explicit permit step.
  # This is the recommended form:
  def create
    Person.create(person_params)
  end

  # This will pass with flying colors as long as there's a person key in the
  # parameters, otherwise it'll raise an ActionController::MissingParameter
  # exception, which will get caught by ActionController::Base and turned
  # into a 400 Bad Request reply.
  def update
    redirect_to current_account.people.find(params[:id]).tap { |person|
      person.update!(person_params)
    }
  end

  private
    # Using a private method to encapsulate the permissible parameters is
    # just a good pattern since you'll be able to reuse the same permit
    # list between create and update. Also, you can specialize this method
    # with per-user checking of permissible attributes.
    def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
    end
end
```

Keep in mind that you will need to specify term inside venue_suggestions with something like

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(venue_suggestion: { term: "something" })
```

Source: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html